# Why do I get a "Sequence contains no elements" error?

Tags: c#

I am using the following to convert the first character of a string to upper and add a period at the end:

```
public static string toUpper (string mytext)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(mytext) || mytext == "") return mytext;

    mytext = mytext.Trim();

    if (mytext.EndsWith("."))
    {
      mytext = mytext.First().ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToUpper()
             + string.Join("", mytext.Skip(1))
             ;
    }
    else
    {
      mytext = mytext.First().ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToUpper()
             + string.Join("", mytext.Skip(1))
             + "."
             ;
    }
    return mytext;
}
```

I get an error Sequence contains no elements if mytext = "" at this line:

```
 mytext = mytext.First().ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToUpper()
        + string.Join("", mytext.Skip(1))
        + "."
        ;
```

Would appreciate your suggestions.

Comment: i had originally miss-read the question. Your first if will produce an error if there's only space in the mytext... use if(String.IsNullOrWhitespace(mytext) || mytext=="") instead.

Comment: The second condition (`mytext == ""`) is redundant.

Comment: agreed and should be removed...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems way more complicated than it has any right to be.

I'd go for elegance and use a regular expression:

```
public static string toUpper( string s )
{
  string value = null ;
  if ( s != null )
  {
    // match length 1: it's the first first character: upper-case it
    // match length 0: the last character isn't a period. append it
    value = rx.Replace( s.Trim() , m => m.Length == 1 ? m.Value.ToUpper( CultureInfo.InvariantCulture ) : "." ) ;
  }
  return value ;
}
static readonly Regex rx = new Regex( @"(^.)|($(?<=[^\.]" ) ;
```

But you could use a string builder...

```
public static string toUpper( string s )
{
  if ( s == null ) return null ;

  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder( s.Trim() ) ;
  if ( sb.Length > 0 )
  {
    sb[0] = char.ToUpper(sb[0] , CultureInfo.InvariantCulture ) ;
    if ( sb[ sb.Length-1] != '.' ) sb.Append('.') ;
  }
  value = sb.ToString() ;
  return value ;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Nicholas, I used the string builder solution.

Answer (score 4):

After the Trim() method, you may have ended up with an empty string, which will cause an exception when you try to grab the first (non-existant) character.

Answer (score 0):

You should trim mytext before you check it. Also IsNullOrEmpty can be used 'standalone'. So try:

```
mytext = mytext.Trim();
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(mytext)) return mytext;
```

Also, if mytext has a length of 1 character then Skip(1) will fail.

Answer (score 0):

your code has bugs . I modified it the following way

```
public static string toUpper(string mytext)
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(mytext)) { return mytext; }

            mytext = mytext.Trim();

            if (mytext.EndsWith("."))
            {
                if (mytext.Length == 1)
                {
                    return mytext;
                }
                else
                {
                    string first = mytext.First();
                    mytext = String.Join(first.ToUpper(), mytext.Substring(1));
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (mytext.Length == 1)
                {
                    mytext = String.Join(mytext.ToUpper, ".");
                }
                else
                {
                    string first = mytext.First();
                    mytext = String.Join(first.ToUpper(), mytext.Substring(1));
                }

            }
            return mytext;
        }
```

Answer (score -3):

use firstordefault() instead of first(). first throwing an exception in case there are no elements

Comment: -1 because even though this prevents the exception, this will give an incorrect result.

Comment: define incorrect result!!! dont simply downvote. he says he is getting exception and my fix should solve it

Comment: please mark as answer if you think my ans helped you.

Comment: @qamar `FirstOrDefault()` will return `default(char)` which is then converted to a string that isn't empty.

Comment: @qamar You miss understood something. Good answers are up voted, but not all accepted answers are good. This just means it helped the OP, but maybe it's a bad suggestions.